# Run Node Red as SU on boot

Tags: node-red

I would like to use Port 502 for my ModBus Server Flow, however, I can only do this if I run "sudo node-red-start"

I have it set to run as a service using "sudo systemctl enable nodered.service"
However, this only seems to execute it as a normal user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `systemctl` with `sudo` has no bearing on what user the resulting service is run as. That is defined in the service file.

You need to edit `nodered.service` file and update the `User` and `Group` settings.

```
...
[Service]
Type=simple
# Run as normal pi user - feel free to change...
User=pi
Group=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
...
```

That file should be located in `/lib/systemd/system/nodered.service`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to the one @knolleary has suggested, which is to allow the pi user to open low ports. This can be done by running the following command:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' `which node`
```

This will allow the node binary bind to ports lower than 1024 as any user.

Be aware that this could be a security issue as it will allow ***any*** user to run NodeJS app that can then pretend to be a system service (e.g. SSH)